# count data that does not fit anything

Tags: poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data

I am trying to build a counts model but my response does not seem to fit anything. If I pull the histogram looks poisson-ish but when I run goodfit() in R, it does not fit poisson or negative binomial. The data has no zeros. What other options do I have and how do I do it in R?

[image: histogram]

Here is the data:
[file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7E0FE4CDF3BCFD0E!5242&authkey=!AFFvpFz2jSoab10&ithint=file%2ccsv)

Comment: Try to do the logarithm of the data and plot again, you will have a better insight. In my opinion there could be two distributions in that data, but you need to test that hypothesis.

Comment: the log fits with a negative binomial quite well. I will use that. Leonardo, do you want to make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: glad it helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to do the logarithm of the data and plot again, you will have a better insight. In my opinion there could be two distributions in that data, but you need to test that hypothesis.