# Distribution when count data have no zero counts

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

My data are monthly counts of samples submitted to a laboratory for testing. The data have no monthly counts of 0 for when no samples were submitted. How should this data be handled? What distribution/family should I be assigning this data when modelling it in R?

I have read [here](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/getting-accurate-predicted-counts-when-there-are-no-zeros-in-the-data/) that Poisson and negative binomial models "can only be used on data where the observations’ outcome have the possibility of having a zero count." However, another post on [StackExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183019/count-data-that-does-not-fit-anything) suggests that other people have just log transformed their data and used a negative binomial distribution/family (in my case I don't think this appropriate, rootogram of fitted model looks very ugly).

I plan to use GAMs to model this data. (Happy to be told that GAMs is/is not a suitable method.)

Comment: Are you saying zero counts occur in the process but can't appear in the data record (that nothing is recorded in that case)? [Do you not retain the dates associated with the monthly counts? Or, for example can you look at 2018 and say "well we got 9 counts in 12 months, so there must be 3 zeros as well"?]. If there's really no way to do that, then you have a zero- truncated distribution

Comment: Thanks. It is not possible to have 0 counts because each count has associated descriptor variables. For example, I may have a monthly count of 5 from domestic animals from location X or I may have a monthly count of 8 from wild animals from location Y. It is obviously not possible to simulate the associated descriptors when the count is 0 because there are no descriptors. Having said that I can obviously identify when no count has been submitted from a particular group of animals in a particular month.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, then a truncated distribution might be worth trying. If the counts have no firm upper limit, then zero-truncated Poisson and zero-truncated negative binomial would be obvious ones to consider

Comment: Sorry all, I think I made a mistake and was just confused. I can simulate zero counts, I just have to do it for every combination of explanatory variables. For example, Australian state and sample type (wild vs domestic) are my main two explanatory variables. I went back to the start of my code and simulated zero counts for every combination of state*sample type where monthly samples were not submitted. I now have lots of zero counts and have gone back to a Poisson model, if data are still overdispersed I will mode to negative binomial and if more zero than expected zero-inflated model. thanks

Comment: Re your comment "it is not possible to simulate:" why not??  Let's focus on each unique combination of descriptors, such as "domestic animals at location X." If no samples were submitted in a given month for that combination, the count is zero.

Comment: Thanks. See my above comment. You are correct, I was confused and have now simulated all the necessary zero counts.